# wso2am 2.6.0: SSL exception when invoking API which uses custom class mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Installed wso2am 2.6.0.

1. Created and published API - `Myapi`. `Myapi` is visible in API store and it can be invoked from there (receives correct response).
2. Created my own custom class demo mediator (nothing fancy, just outputs some information) and uploaded it to `<API-M_HOME>/repository/components/lib`.
3. Created sequence xml with my own custom class and manually uploaded it for `Myapi` (in API publisher 'Enabled message Mediation', for 'In Flow').
4. Restarted server and it looks like registered my custom class mediator successfully.

But now then i try to invoke this API through API store it throws such exception:

```
[2019-03-23 21:04:00,858] ERROR - SourceHandler I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-03-23 21:04:00,874]  INFO - LogMediator IN_MESSAGE = json_validator
[2019-03-23 21:04:00,879]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error occured in the mediation of the class mediator
```

Same issue happens when i selected another i.e. `json_validator` mediator (which is not my custom, so issue is not just in my custom mediator), but i.e. with `debug_in_flow` mediator everything works.
It seems that this issue appears when mediator uses some class mediator and then it throws this SSL exception.

Any ideas where certificate should be added? As I understand inner service tries to invoke custom java class without certificate and fails.

Comment: Invoking Java class has nothing to do with any certificate. The exception indeed indicates, that something is trying to call a https endpoint and the ssl handshake fails. It is not clear if it's from your custom mediation or the service target endpoint. `Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`   this may indicate the endpoint requires a client certificate for mutual ssl. Do you have it configured?

Comment: @gusto, custom mediator is very simple, it outputs just a string to log. And target endpoint is http (without mediator everything is working).

Comment: With the given information, this behavior is very strange. I feel something is missing in the description. You said your API worked before attaching the sequence. I have 2 questions. (1) If you set in sequence `None`, does that work again? (2) If you remove your jar from lib and set `json_validator` does that work?

Comment: @Bee, thanks for suggestion, your thoughts gave me an idea to reinstall wso2am server from scratch (as there were some configuration made before) and now it throws this exception all the time, but it doesn't affect mediation flow - custom mediator is being invoked anyway (I've updated it a little bit and now it logs information). Also I think that this exception is because wso2am runs on my vagrant ubuntu box and I try to access wso2am from my host computer, not from localhost.

Comment: What is your deployment like? A single node one? and do you have a loadbalancer in the front?

Comment: It's default ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant box installed with apt-get (https://wso2.com/api-management/install/apt/), I guess one node, no loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is throwing, but it doesn't affect custom mediator flow.